# Вопрос из олимпидаы

Tags: литература

Прочитайте отрывок из романа «Герой нашего времени» и назовите фамилию человека, о котором идёт речь в приведенном монологе.

«Давно уж не слышно было ни звона колокольчика, ни стука колес по кремнистой дороге, - а бедный старик еще стоял на том же месте в глубокой задумчивости.
- Да, - сказал он наконец, стараясь принять равнодушный вид, хотя слеза досады по временам сверкала на его ресницах, - конечно, мы были приятели, -ну, да что приятели в нынешнем веке!..

Я дал ответ: Максимович. Оказалось ошибкой. Ведь до этого  описывается разговор Максимовича с Печорином. Может, я неправ или что-то недопонял?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...назовите фамилию человека, о котором идёт речь в приведенном
>   монологе.

В монологе **Максима Максимыча** говорится **о ком-то**, с кем ранее Максим Максимыч состоял в приятельских отношениях.

**О ком** идёт речь? **О *Печорине*.**

Comment: Спасибо. Вчера я пробовал и вариант с "Печорином", давало мне ошибку. Видимо, сбой в сети.

Comment: Требуется фамилия, а Вы назвали отчество, и то неверно, надо "Максимыч". По смыслу вопроса нужна фамилия человека, о котором говорится в монологе Максима Максимыча, следовательно, Печорин. Может, Вы тоже с ошибкой написали?(с Ё, например?)

Answer (score 0):

Плохо сформулирован вопрос. Но в общем-то можно догадаться, что речь идет о монологе Максима Максимыча, а сам монолог посвящен воспоминаниям и рассуждениям о Печорине.